# PDFTron : - how to get pdf file from gridfs (mongodb), add watermark in it and send it to client?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, pdftron

I am using **Gridfs** to store large files in **mognodb**.
Now I am using **PDFTron** for pdf editing and want to **watermark** pdf.
The problem is i am not able to read file from Gridfs stream in pdftron nodejs sdk.
also i want to send it back to the client without storing it locally or anywhere else.

I am doing something like this...

```
const bucket = new mongodb.GridFSBucket(db);
const stream = bucket.openDownloadStream(ObjectId(file_id))
const pdfdoc = await PDFNet.PDFDoc.createFromFilter(stream);
```

the error i am getting is ...
**TypeError: 1st input argument in function 'createFromFilter' is of type 'object'. Expected type 'Filter'. Function Signature: createFromFilter(PDFNet.Filter)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PDFDoc.createFromFilter` API is expecting a PDFNet Filter, not whatever GridFS is returning.
https://www.pdftron.com/api/pdfnet-node/PDFNet.PDFDoc.html#.createFromFilter__anchor

You can see this sample on creating a PDFDoc object from a Filter
https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/samples/node/js/PDFDocMemoryTest

Though the easiest is to write your GridFD stream to a buffer, and then pass that buffer to PDFDoc.createFromBuffer. https://www.pdftron.com/api/pdfnet-node/PDFNet.PDFDoc.html#.createFromBuffer__anchor

Comment: I tried third Solution and it worked..thanks.